# DictReader finding match in csv but getting false positive

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm writing a Python3.x script to match certain text in a large CSV file. I'm very close to getting what I'm looking for, but for some reason I'm getting a false positive. Below is my code:

```
from csv import DictReader

def cluster_lookup():
    cluster = input("What cluster are you looking for? ")
    while True:
        try:
            with open('hypervisor.csv') as csvfile:
                reader = DictReader(csvfile)
                for col in reader:
                    if col['cluster_name'] == cluster:
                        print(', '.join([col['host_name'], col['ip']]))
                        continue
        except IOError as err:
            print('Could not locate the csv file.', err)
            break
        else:
            if col['cluster_name'] is not cluster:
                print('The cluster cannot be found.')
                break
```

Expected output:

```
What cluster are you looking for? cluster 15
server150, 192.x.x.x
server151, 192.x.x.x
server152, 192.x.x.x
server153, 192.x.x.x
server154, 192.x.x.x
server155, 192.x.x.x
server156, 192.x.x.x
server157, 192.x.x.x
server158, 192.x.x.x
server159, 192.x.x.x
```

Instead it's finding the cluster I'm looking for but also returns `The cluster cannot be found`

Comment: The else clause will be called whenever an exception is not generated. At this point col will contain the last element from the reader. If the last element does not match, the error message is printed. A better method would be to set a flag to True in the if col[]-clause, and then check the flag in the else clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cluster_lookup():
   cluster = input("What cluster are you looking for? ")
   try:
       with open('hypervisor.csv') as csvfile:
           reader = DictReader(csvfile)
           isFound = False
           for col in reader:
               if col['cluster_name'] == cluster:
                   print(', '.join([col['host_name'], col['ip']]))
                   isFound = True
           if(isFound == False):
               print('The cluster cannot be found.')
               exit()
   except IOError as err:
       print('Could not locate the csv file.', err)
       exit()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I didn't need the `while` loop and I just needed to remove the `else` statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The else condition checks only against the last value of col, which if does not match prints The cluster cannot be found. You should instead use a boolean variable which checks if the cluster has been found or not

```
found = False
try:
   with open('hypervisor.csv') as csvfile:
   reader = DictReader(csvfile)
   for col in reader:
        if col['cluster_name'] == cluster:
           print(', '.join([col['host_name'], col['ip']]))
           found = True
           continue
except IOError as err:
        print('Could not locate the csv file.', err)
        break
    else:
        if not found:
            print('The cluster cannot be found.')
            break
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. When I add the boolean variable and run the script it now returns all host_names and ip's in the csv file.